# VS Code Glob pattern optional single character

Tags: visual-studio-code, glob

Using the VS Code "files to include" feature in search, I'd like to search for any Javascript file within a folder, including `[.js, .ts, .jsx, .tsx]` but not `.json`. I can already to this with 2 separate searches:

`./theFolder/**/*.[tj]s, ./theFolder/**/*.[tj]sx`

Is there a way to do it with just one, like it would be in Regex?

`./theFolder/**/*.[tj]sx? // ? doesn't do that in vscode glob`

Also see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/glob-patterns

Comment: Is this for the `files to exclude` input box in a Search view or for the `Search: Exclude` setting?  Or something else?  Do you mean the `files to include` - which looks like what you are trying to do but you say "Exclude files".

Comment: To include your list but not json files, does `theFolder/**/*.{ts,js,tsx,jsx}` work for you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the time of this writing, there's no single-optional-character matching feature.

But you can still make what you're doing less verbose by using `{}` to group conditions. Ex. `./theFolder/**/*.{[tj]s,[tj]sx}`.

For docs, in addition to https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/glob-patterns, see also https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/codebasics#_advanced-search-options